# udev rule to match a partition flag

Tags: partition, windows, udev

I am trying to run a Windows partition in VirtualBox, and I would like to create a udev rule that identifies Windows partitions and changes the group to *vboxusers*. Currently, I have udev set to match the partitions by UUID, but I would like to make them more generic.

Here are my current rules:

```
# Rules to give VirtualBox raw access to Windows partitions

# Microsoft Reserved partition
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{transport}=="pcie", ENV{ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID}=="df9bb75d-81b8-41cc-9faa-067f21b7089c", RUN+="/bin/chgrp vboxusers /dev/$name"

# Windows partition
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{transport}=="pcie", ENV{ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID}=="8bad4d16-593c-4d50-a315-c8b33555888f", RUN+="/bin/chgrp vboxusers /dev/$name"
```

Instead of using *ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID*, I would like these rules to match the `msftres` and `msftdata` partition flags. Is this possible?

I've tried listing attributes and variables using `udevadm info -n /dev/???`, but haven't seen anything related to partition flags.

Comment: My first idea would be to write a custom shell script to get the partition flags, run it inside the `udev` rule with `PROGRAM`, and match on the results. See `man udev`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GPT disks, UUIDs have been assigned to various partitions *types*. This is a different parameter for  For disks connected to the system, use `lsblk -o +PARTTYPE`.

The udev rule now looks like this:

```
# Rules to give VirtualBox users raw access to Windows partitions

# Microsoft Reserved partitions (msftres)
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE}=="e3c9e316-0b5c-4db8-817d-f92df00215ae", GROUP="vboxusers"

# Windows basic data partitions (msftdata)
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE}=="ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7", GROUP="vboxusers"
```

Note that this will only work on a disk partitioned using GPT. In order to detect Windows partitions on MBR disks, a different technique will be needed.

---

### UUID Environment Variables

Since udev can access a variety of UUID environment variables, I've listed them here.

- `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID`: unique for a particular partition table, can be used to uniquely identify a disk in most cases
- `ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE`: unique for a particular type of partition. A list of GPT partition types is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs).
- `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID`: uniquely identifies a GPT partition
- `ID_FS_UUID`: uniquely identifies a filesystem

  - Changes if the partition is reformatted
  - If a particular filesystem does not support UUIDs, a shorter identifier is used.